# running a exe file from web api on iis server not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to execute an exe file on to The Web API as and when user request comes. It is working perfectly but when I am hosting web API to server the exe file is not executed when user request comes. What to do for executing the exe file from web API on IIS server?

Here is the process starting code:

```
public static void Start(long campaign_id, long contact_id, string startDate, string endDate, string user)
{
    try
    {
        //WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/c sparkclr-submit --master " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SparkMaster"] + " --driver-class-path " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Engine\\mysql.jar " + "--exe CmAnalyticsEngine.exe " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Engine " + campaign_id + " " + contact_id + " " + startDate + " " + endDate + " " + user;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogWritter.WriteErrorLog(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: you must give your iis user permission for execution.

Comment: i have given permissions for iis user to the directory having exe file and also the application pool but still not working

Answer (score 2):

How are you starting the exe? You have any error logs?

You can try using the verb `runas` in `Process.Start` to execute the exe file as an Administrator.

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
proc.FileName = myExePath;
proc.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Verb = "runas"; //this is how you pass this verb
```

Comment: @Milhail how to do that do i need to pass argument with process.start()?

Comment: i have try giving this verb run as but still no output is there, thanks

Comment: Is the app you are trying to run x64?